# Root Record sharing from CoreData -> CloudKit mirror

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

This is a request for clarification/explanation more than anything. I've spent weeks upon weeks trying everything I can.

I have a CoreData -> CloudKit app where I'd like to publicly share a hierarchy of records that matches the relationships in CoreData. It is a school app, so a school has relationships with students and courses which have relationships for enrollments and quizzes and grades etc.

It was my understanding that if I share a school as a root record, it would share all the courses, students, quizzes etc without needing to do anything else other than define the CoreData relationships and create the rootRecord share. From what I can see, it only shares the root record and I need to create all the CloudKit relationships. Am I wrong?

If I do need to create those relationships, how do I get the CloudKit record name (recordID) associated with the affected CoreData items?

I'm thinking I'd need to do something like this:

```
import Foundation
import CloudKit

func createShareHierarchy(stack: CoreDataStack, school: School) async
{
    do
    {
        if let share = stack.getSchoolShare(school: school)
        {
            print(share.debugDescription)
            for course in school.courseArray
            {
                if let cs = stack.getShare(course)
                {
                    print("\(course.title!) ok")
                    if cs.parent == nil
                    {
                        print("No parent")
                        // set parent here???
                        // cs.parent = CKRecord(...
                    }
                    // drill down to course relationships, etc...
                } else
                {
                    let (_, newshare, _) = try await CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.share([course], to: share)
                    newshare[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = course.title!
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Even though I have manually created shares of some students and courses using the CloudKit console just to prove it would work, the above code indicated that none of the courses or students have a parent and they all, even ones I haven't touched, show they have a share. I'm soooo confused.

Rather than impose any code errors, I created the record share and the relationships for a few test records and then I manually insert a parent/child share, that works.

As a point of reference, multiple devices signed into iCloud as the owner get synched just fine, but on devices that accept the share, I'm only getting the data that has been shared by my including the parent reference for sharing.

Any ideas?